# AngularJS validation error variable not being set

Tags: angularjs

Why isn't the error variable being set here? Shouldn't `user.username.$error.minlength` be true when no value is in the input?

```
<form name="user" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="12" />
        <div ng-show="user.username.$error.minlength">Min length!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="15" />
        <div ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.minlength">Min length!</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need a name attribute on each input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to show the message when there is no value for the password you need to check the `required` property.

put a name for the form

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="submit()">
```

put a name to `password` input. and the required attribute

```
<input name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="15" required />
```

change the `ng-show` as,

```
 <div ng-show="formName.password.$error.required || formName.password.$error.minlength">Min length!</div>
```

`formName.password.$error.required` will handle the status of empty input.

here is a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiLz8rU4zPQdXRY16JPz?p=preview)